# Suggestion need for Code sharing Onsite Offsite

Tags: java, eclipse, code-sharing

I am new to a project where developers still share code by sending files by mail.
We are using eclipse and cvs.

Developers from offsite send there code for reveiw to onsite where other developers take files one by one from there mail and replace in eclipse. It is ok for 2 or 3 files. But as the files keep on increasing this task really becomes a pain.

We cannot put the source files into the cvs as untested code from offsite can crash our build server.
  Here my question begins:-

What can be the better ways to share code?

We dont want to create branches for each change because in this case we will end up with 10-12 branches everyday.

Comment: Have you looked into either using a distributed scm (perhaps GIT) or allowing the offshore folks to access the CVS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code should be tested via continuous integration, *especially* in your situation where your programmers are scattered literally across the world.  Your offshore people should be using unit/integration testing to insure that they don't break the build.  You should institute process where before they finish for the day, they verify the integrity of the build.
If they are not, they are not worth the money you are paying them.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you give the offsite developers the ability to perform the same test as your build server.  There is no reason they should be sending you code which they cannot test (or test that it at least runs without crashing).

Is there any reason they cannot access your systems via VPN.  That way they can test the code via your's or a second build server and merge the code themselves.